# CakePHP 2.2 validation trim() error

Tags: cakephp, trim, cakephp-2.2

This is quite strange, I have a text input in a registration form and when I am setting the $validate array in the model, I am getting a trim() error - Warning (2): trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 754]

Form input

```
<?=$this->Form->input("lastname", array("label" => array("text" => "Last name *"), "class" => "required", "div" => array("class" => array("input text last")))); ?>
```

Model validate array

```
public $validate = array(
        'lastname' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Last name is required'
            )
        )
    );
```

It seems that when I am doing a validation rule for that field, the div styling array - "div" => array("class" => array("input text last")) is causing the error. I added the following code to the Helper.php file as a workaround:

```
if(is_array($options["class"])) {
            $options["class"] = $options["class"][0];
        }
```

but I would like to know why it is causing this error.

Answer (score 2):

Too many nested arrays for the Form Helper. Try this:

```
$this->Form->input("lastname", array(
    "label" => "Last name", 
    "id" => "MyInputDiv",
    "class" => "input text last required"));
```

`array("text" => "Last name *")` You don't need an array here if you are just setting the text value of the label. Array is reserved for html attributes.

`"div" => array("class" => array("input text last"))` Not familiar with this in the formHelper. Perhaps you were looking for the `before` and `after` attributes to set the wrapping div of the element [here](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/form-helper%20here).

Comment: yes, that was the problem "div" => array("class" => array("input text last")) should be "div" => array("class" => "input text last")